# Custome Metadata getAll() vs SOQL query

Tags: soql, governorlimits, custom-metadata

I have checked in official documentation that we can use getAll() method to query all metadata records. My apprehension is that does it actually run a SOQL in the background and consume the governor limit. Any information on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't run a SOQL so it doesn't count against governor limits. Indeed the [`getAll()` documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_metadata_types.htm#apex_System_CustomMetadataType_getall) states (emphasis mine):

> To iterate over the list of custom metadata type record sObjects, use `getAll().values()`. **Only the first 255 characters are returned for any field** in a custom metadata type record, so longer text fields get truncated. **If you want all the field data from a custom metadata type record, use a SOQL query**.

That part is often overlooked. It means that if you have a long text area field, you **need** a SOQL to get the whole text and it will count against the governor limits, as stated [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_limits.htm&type=5).

Anyway, if in Apex you query a custom metadata that doesn't contain long text area fields, it won't count against the governor limits, while it counts toward governor limits if the query happens in a flow.

Comment: I agree with your inference and thanks for highlighting that.